# GAE and JPA 2.0 "eclipselink.cache.shared.default" is a legacy entity caching property

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-1.0

According to google I can use JPA 2.0 but I should do it with the xml descriptor for version JPA 1.0:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2#Setting_Up_JPA_2_0

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
```

So if I want to disable the shared caching I should use:

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />
```

which is resulting in warning :

```
"eclipselink.cache.shared.default" is a legacy entity caching property. Consider migration to JPA 2.0 and EclipseLink cache settings via annotation or XML mapping file
```

But again I cannot use JPA persistence xml descriptor for JPA 2.0. How to get rid of this warning? Using whatever tag that is for JPA 2.0 is resulting in error. Thank you for the help!

Comment: define what is your JPA implementation? EclipseLink, GAE/J JPA ? You refer to GAE docs which is not for EclipseLink.

Comment: Try: <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode> http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache%3F

Comment: Invalid content was found starting with element 'shared-cache-mode'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":description, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":provider, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/
 persistence":jta-data-source, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":non-jta-data-source, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":mapping-file, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":jar-file, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":class, 
 "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":exclude-unlisted-classes, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":properties}' is expected.

Comment: The GAE JPA page is wrong. You should put the XSD descriptor for JPA 2.0 when using it in a JPA 2 context.

Comment: Yes. Thank you! Now the persistence.xml file looks really great. I was with the impression that JPA 2.0 annotation doesn't work because <shared-cache-mode> tag followed by  <class> tag was showing error. Also I removed all <class> tags with <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> and set in eclipse: "discover annotated classes automatically"